# Few Python commands aborted without any error on MacOS Catalina

Tags: python, flask, virtualenv, pyenv

Few commands on my Laptop like `flask fab`, `fabmanager`, `superset` are aborted without any error message and I can't figure out what is wrong here

```sh
$ which python
/Users/azharkhan/Work/incubator-superset/venv2/bin/python

$ python --version
Python 3.7.7

$ which flask
/Users/azharkhan/Work/incubator-superset/venv2/bin/flask

$ which fabmanager
/Users/azharkhan/Work/incubator-superset/venv2/bin/fabmanager

$ which superset
/Users/azharkhan/Work/incubator-superset/venv2/bin/superset
```

And when I try and run them, I get

```sh
$ flask fab create-user
[1]    49559 abort      flask fab create-user

$ superset run
[1]    49600 abort      superset run
```

I have tested same with `python3.6` and got same result

As asked by @triplee
Adding some some details here

```sh
$ ls -l /Users/azharkhan/Work/incubator-superset/venv2/bin/flask
-rwxr-xr-x  1 azharkhan  staff  247 12 Jun 14:40 /Users/azharkhan/Work/incubator-superset/venv2/bin/flask

$ file /Users/azharkhan/Work/incubator-superset/venv2/bin/flask
/Users/azharkhan/Work/incubator-superset/venv2/bin/flask: a /Users/azharkhan/Work/incubator-superset/venv2/bin/python3 script text executable, ASCII text

$ cat /Users/azharkhan/Work/incubator-superset/venv2/bin/flask
#!/Users/azharkhan/Work/incubator-superset/venv2/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys
from flask.cli import main
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())
```

Info about underlying python

```sh
$ ls -l /Users/azharkhan/Work/incubator-superset/venv2/bin/python3
lrwxr-xr-x  1 azharkhan  staff  50 12 Jun 14:29 /Users/azharkhan/Work/incubator-superset/venv2/bin/python3 -> /Users/azharkhan/.pyenv/versions/3.7.7/bin/python3

$ file /Users/azharkhan/Work/incubator-superset/venv2/bin/python3
/Users/azharkhan/Work/incubator-superset/venv2/bin/python3: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64

$ cat /Users/azharkhan/Work/incubator-superset/ak/bin/python3 | less
<CF><FA><ED><FE>^G^@^@^A^C^@^@<80>^B^@^@^@^Q^@^@^@^@^G^@^@<85>^@ ^@^@^@^@^@^Y^@^@^@H^@^@^@__PAGEZERO^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^A^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^Y^@^@^@(^B^@^@__TEXT^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^A^@^@^@^@`^_^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@`^_^@^@^@^@^@^E^@^@^@^E^@^@^@^F^@^@^@^@^@^@^@__text^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@__TEXT^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@0
^@^@^A^@^@^@.<F7>^Y^@^@^@^@^@0
^@^@^D^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^D^@<80>^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@__stubs^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@__TEXT^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^^A^Z^@^A^@^@^@<96>^F^@^@^@^@^@^@^^A^Z^@^A^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^H^D^@<80>^@^@^@^@^F^@^@^@^@^@^@^@__stub_helper^@^@^@__TEXT^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@<F4>^G^Z^@^A^@^@^@
^K^@^@^@^@^@^@<F4>^G^Z^@^B^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^D^@<80>^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@__cstring^@^@^@^@^@^@^@__TEXT^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@<FE>^R^Z^@^A^@^@^@h:^B^@^@^@^@^@<FE>^R^Z^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^B^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@__const^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@__TEXT^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@pM^\^@^A^@^@^@{<E6>^B^@^@^@^@^@pM
^\^@^D^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@__unwind_info^@^@^@__TEXT^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@<EC>3^_^@^A^@^@^@^L,^@^@^@^@^@^@<EC>3^_^@^B^@^@^@^@
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^Y^@^@^@<E8>^@^@^@__DATA_CONST^@^@^@^@^@`^_^@^A^@^@^@^@0^@^@^@^@^@^@^@`^_^@^@^@^@^@^@0^@^@^@^@^@^@^C^@^@^@^C^@
^@^@^B^@^@^@^P^@^@^@__got^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@__DATA_CONST^@^@^@^@^@`^_^@^A^@^@^@<B8>^A^@^@^@^@^@^@^@`^_^@^C^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^F^@^@^@^Y^A^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@__const^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@__DATA_CONST^@^@^@^@<C0>a^_^@^A^@^@^@@ ^@^@^@^@^@^@<C0>a^_^@^D^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^Y^@^@^@
<88>^A^@^@__DATA^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@<90>^_^@^A^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@<90>^_^@^@^@^@^@^@ ^F^@^@^@^@^@^C^@^@^@^C^@^@^@^D^@^@^@^@^@^@^@__la_symbol_ptr^@__DATA^@
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@<90>^_^@^A^@^@^@<C8>^H^@^@^@^@^@^@^@<90>^_^@^C^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^G^@^@^@P^A^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@__data^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@__DATA^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@И^_^@^A^@^@^@<8B>^S^F^@^@^@^@^@И^_^@^D^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@__bss^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@__DATA^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@`<AC>%^@^A^@^@^@<C1><FC>^A^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^D^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^A^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@__common^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@__DATA^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@0<A9>'^@^A^@^@^@<D0>^G^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^D^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^A^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^Y^@^@^@H^@^@^@__LINKEDIT^@^@^@^@^@^@^@<C0>'^@^A^@^@^@^@^@^M^@^@^@^@^@^@<B0>%^@^@^@^@^@l<F8>^L^@^@^@^@^@^A^@^@^@^A^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@"^@^@<80>0^@^@^@^@<B0>%^@<C0>"^@^@<C0><D2>%^@<C8>^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@<88><D3>%^@H^S^@^@<D0><E6>%^@0<97>^@^@^B^@^@^@^X^@^@^@ <9C>&^@4r^@^@^D<C9>-^@h<DF>^D^@^K^@^@^@P^@^@^@^@^@^@^@<DA>i^@^@<DA>i^@^@:^G^@^@^Tq^@^@ ^A^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@`<BF>-^@i^B^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^N^@^@^@ ^@^@^@^L^@^@^@/usr/lib/dyld^@^@^@^@^@^@^@@^@^@^X^@^@^@<C8>O]<B1>A<EE>4Ţ<97><F0><9C>V<CB><E8><E6>2^@^@^@ ^@^@^@^A^@^@^@^@^O
^@^@^O
^@^A^@^@^@^C^@^@^@^@^@^R^B*^@^@^@^P^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@(^@^@<80>^X^@^@^@0
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^A^@^@^@^@^L^@^@^@h^@^@^@^X^@^@^@^B^@^@^@^@~<89>^F^@^@<96>^@/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation^@
```

Comment: This suggests that the virtual environment symlinked these commands to files which are not proper Mac binaries, but your information doesn't contain enough information to establish anything more detailed than that.

Comment: @tripleee 
what more information will help it debug more?
I can add them. Also, I have also tried deleting and recreating binaries

Comment: `ls -l /Users/azharkhan/Work/incubator-superset/venv2/bin/flask` and perhaps a hex dump of the first few bytes of the file it points to could be a good start, and/or the output of `file /Users/azharkhan/Work/incubator-superset/venv2/bin/flask` (or, again, the file it points to if it's a symlink).

Comment: @tripleee Added those. Nothing seems off there 

Comment: It points to `/Users/azharkhan/Work/incubator-superset/venv2/bin/python3` which might have issues, can you add that too?

Comment: @tripleee added that as well

Comment: Can you run that application `python3` without having it abort? The error message looks like maybe some system feature (anti-malware? out of memory?) terminated the process, but only vaguely. Do you see anything in system logs?

Answer (score -1):

I think this issue is specific to MacOS Catalina. The same issue is coming in my laptop also.
After updating Catalina to Bigsur, I am not facing this issue.